# How to correctly call a variadic template function from a variadic macro?

Tags: c++, macros, c++14, variadic-templates, variadic-macros

Alright, first things first, I will be providing the code I am asking my question for.

### EX_Factory.h

```
#ifndef EX_FACTORY_H
#define EX_FACTORY_H

#include <string>
#include <map>
#include "Base.h"

struct EX_Factory{
    template<class U, typename... Args>
    static void registerC(const std::string &name){
        registry<Args...>[name] = &create<U>;
    }
    template<typename... Args>
    static Base * createObject(const std::string &key, Args... args){
        auto it = registry<Args...>.find(key);
        if(it == registry<Args...>.end()) return nullptr;
        return it->second(args...);
    }
    private:
        EX_Factory() = delete;
        template<typename... Args>
        static std::map<std::string, Base*(*)(Args...)> registry;

        template<class U, typename... Args>
        static Base* create(Args... args){
            return new U(args...);
        }
};

template<typename... Args>
std::map<std::string, Base*(*)(Args...)> EX_Factory::registry;

template<typename U, typename... Args>
struct MiddleMan{
    MiddleMan(const std::string &name){
        EX_Factory::registerC<U,Args...>(name);
    }
};
  #define REGISTER_MACRO(NAME, TYPE, ...)\ // Updated the macro here
    static MiddleMan<TYPE, ##__VA_ARGS__> mm_##TYPE(#NAME);

#endif
```

The code above is a header file for my Factory Design Pattern class.  It allows the user of this class to register constructors for objects derived from the **Base** class with varying arguments.

Alright, quick explanation for why I am using __VA_ARGS__ vs ##__VA_ARGS__, the reason for this is, there will always be at least 1 argument, the template type U in the registerC template function, passed into the macro.

**What I am trying to do is construct a preprocessor macro,** ***REGISTER_MACRO*** **, to register derived classes before runtime.  How do I call a *Variadic Template Function* from a *Variadic Macro* correctly?**

### Tests or main.cpp

```
#include "EX_Factory_1.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct derived_1 : public Base{
    derived_1(int i, int j, float f){
        cout << "Derived 1:\t" << i * j + f << endl;
    }
};
REGISTER_MACRO(name_1, derived_1, int,int,float);
struct derived_2 : public Base{
    derived_2(int i, int j){
        cout << "Derived 2:\t" << i + j << endl;
    }
};
REGISTER_MACRO(name_2, derived_2, int,int);

int main(){ // Program segfaults before entering main
    derived_1 * d_1 = static_cast<derived_1*>(EX_Factory::createObject<int, int, float>("name_1", 8, 8, 3.0));
    if(d_1 == nullptr) cout << "Why is it null?" << endl;
    else{
        delete d_1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The errors I am receiving from trying to compile the above code:
*See **Edit** below*

```
In file included from test.cpp:1:0:
EX_Factory.h:39:38: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘(’ token
    EX_Factory::registerC<__VA_ARGS__>(NAME);
                                      ^
test.cpp:11:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘REGISTER_MACRO’
 REGISTER_MACRO("derived_1",derived_1,int,int,float)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
EX_Factory.h:39:38: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘(’ token
    EX_Factory::registerC<__VA_ARGS__>(NAME);
                                      ^
test.cpp:17:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘REGISTER_MACRO’
 REGISTER_MACRO("derived_2",derived_2,int,int)
```

I am using the **g++ 6.3** compiler, so by default, it compiles with **C++14** standards in an Ubuntu 16.04 environment.

Potential solutions I've found, but don't fit my problem:

[Is there a way to define variadic template macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16159204/is-there-a-way-to-define-variadic-template-macro)

[Using variadic macros or templates to implement a set of functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18237350/using-variadic-macros-or-templates-to-implement-a-set-of-functions)

Potential Solution but could not interpret its solution:

[How to use variadic template with variadic macro ?](https://forum.qt.io/topic/55761/solved-how-to-use-variadic-template-with-variadic-macro/9)
*I'm not using QT, and I am using a fully supported C++11 compiler.*

### **Edit**

I now know why my file will not compile, but I do not know how to handle creating an object to call the method for myself.  I added a middle man class, MiddleMan, and added a call to the static registerC class to its constructor and modified my macro to create static references to this class.  This allows my program to compile, but it segfaults with this method.  You will see the mentioned reflections above now.

I am testing this class and macro out with my main.cpp in my answer to [this question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/17746/entity-component-systems-in-c-how-do-i-discover-types-and-construct-component/140969#140969).

Comment: This has nothing to do with macros; the problem is that you can't write a function call in namespace scope.

Comment: @T.C. Sure you can -  `int n = strlen("");`

Comment: @NeilButterworth Fine, an expression-statement.

Comment: @T.C. What do you mean by write a function in namespace scope?  I'm calling a static function, so I am confused by your statement.

Comment: @kennethCornett: At namespace scope, you can only write declarations. A function call is not a declaration, even if the function is static.

Comment: @rici Thank you for the explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, with the help from @rici , a little research, and the prior mention for the reason from @T.C. I developed a modified design which uses a **Registrator** object to register *Derived Objects* of *Base* into my Factory design.

To bypass the segfaults I was experiencing, I decided to implement Functors to store my **template create** functions.  I designed a base functor, **F**, and a template derived functor, **DF**.

I created a *getMap()* method which returned the **reference** to a static map object which stored *std::string* and *base functor pointer,**F****, pairs in it.

***My Solution's Code Below!***

### FunctorFactory.h

```
#ifndef FUNCTOR_FACTORY_H
#define FUNCTOR_FACTORY_H

#include <map>
#include <string>

#include "Base.h"

struct FunctorFactory{
    private:
        class F{ // Base Functor
            public:
                virtual ~F(){}
        };
        template<typename R, typename... A>
        struct DF : public F{ // Templated Derived Functors
            DF(R (*f)(A...)); // Regular Constructor
            DF(const DF<R,A...>& df); // Copy Constructor
            virtual ~DF(); // Virtual Destructor
            virtual R operator()(A... args); // Overloaded () to allow function like use.
            virtual DF<R,A...>& operator=(const DF<R,A...>& df); // Overloaded = to allow assignment

            private:
                R (*_f)(A...); // The actual function being called
        };
        static std::map<std::string,F*>& getMap(); // Map pairing string keys to their Functors(stored as Base Functors)
        template<typename U, typename... A> // Templated create function which will create the derived objects being requested!
        static Base * create(A... args);
    public:
        template<typename U, typename... A> // Registrator class which registers objects
        struct Registrator{
            Registrator(const std::string &key);
        };
        template<typename... A> // createObject static method which creates the requested object
        static Base * createObject(const std::string &skey, A... args);
};

// Implementation of the derived functor's methods
template<typename R, typename... A> // Basic Constructor.
FunctorFactory::DF<R,A...>::DF(R (*f)(A...)){_f = f;}
template<typename R, typename... A> // Copy Constructor.
FunctorFactory::DF<R,A...>::DF(const FunctorFactory::DF<R,A...>& df){_f = df._f;}
template<typename R, typename... A> // Destructor
FunctorFactory::DF<R,A...>::~DF(){}
template<typename R, typename... A> // Overloaded () operator
R FunctorFactory::DF<R,A...>::operator()(A... args){return _f(args...);}
template<typename R, typename... A> // Overloaded = operator
FunctorFactory::DF<R,A...>& FunctorFactory::DF<R,A...>::operator=(const FunctorFactory::DF<R,A...>& df){_f = df._f;}

std::map<std::string,FunctorFactory::F*>& FunctorFactory::getMap(){ // Get map class
    static std::map<std::string,FunctorFactory::F*> m_map; // The actual map storing the functors.
    return m_map;
}

template<typename U, typename... A>
Base * FunctorFactory::create(A... args){
    return new U(args...);
}

template<typename U, typename... A>
FunctorFactory::Registrator<U,A...>::Registrator(const std::string &key){
    DF<Base*,A...> * df = new DF<Base*,A...>(FunctorFactory::create<U,A...>);
    getMap()[key] = df;
}
template<typename... A>
Base * FunctorFactory::createObject(const std::string &skey, A... args){
    auto it = getMap().find(skey);
    if(it == getMap().end()) return nullptr;
    DF<Base*,A...> * df = static_cast<DF<Base*,A...>*>(it->second);
    return (*df)(args...);
}

    #ifndef FF_MACRO
        #define FF_MACRO(NAME,TYPE,...)\
            namespace { \
                ::FunctorFactory::Registrator<TYPE,##__VA_ARGS__> registrator_##NAME(#NAME); \
            }
    #endif

#endif // FUNCTOR_FACTORY_H
```

### Base.h

```
#ifndef BASE_H
#define BASE_H

class Base{
    public:
        virtual ~Base(){}
};

#endif
```

### main.cpp

```
#include "FunctorFactory.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct derived_1 : public Base{
    derived_1(int i, int j, float f){
        cout << "Derived 1:\t" << i * j + f << endl;
    }
};
FF_MACRO(name_1, derived_1, int,int,float);

struct derived_2 : public Base{
    derived_2(int i, int j){
        cout << "Derived 2:\t" << i + j << endl;
    }
};
FF_MACRO(name_2, derived_2, int,int);

int main(){
    derived_1 * d_1 = static_cast<derived_1*>(FunctorFactory::createObject<int, int, float>("name_1", 8, 8, 3.0));
    if(d_1 == nullptr) cout << "The function being requested must either have different parameters or a different key." << endl;
    else{
        delete d_1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

### Output

```
Derived 1:  67
```

I hope this helps anyone who comes across a similar problem to this.
Feel free to use this Factory Model as well if you need to.  It is able to store multiple different mappings for overloaded constructors to the same object type as well as multiple different derived objects.